# In magento pwa sites how we can improve SEO LCP score

Tags: seo, react-js, scandipwa

> we have a background image for banner and it is taking to much time to load
> in admin we'll be having background image not these details. i need to apply rel="preload" to this .. how can i add them to increase LCP score. where i can add if source path is not specified.

< <div
class="pagebuilder-slide-wrapper bg-image-jdhf7 bg-image-9kgr0 bg-image-kpolb bg-image-cqu2f"data-background-images="{&quot;desktop_image&quot;:&quot;[https://xyz.com/media/wysiwyg/sman_1920x566px_authentic_strains_BLANK.jpg\](https://xyz.com/media/wysiwyg/sman_1920x566px_authentic_strains_BLANK.jpg%5C)",&quot;mobile_image&quot;:&quot;[https://xyz.com/media/wysiwyg/sman_480x528px_authentic_strains_BLANK.jpg\](https://xyz.com/media/wysiwyg/sman_480x528px_authentic_strains_BLANK.jpg%5C)"}" data-background-type="image" data-video-loop="true" data-video-play-only-visible="true" data-video-lazy-load="true" data-video-fallback-src data-element="wrapper" data-pb-style="NHLX8S1">

>

> this is the image of page speed

> this is the report given by page speed how can change the core web vital Failed to pass
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcAZY.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.